# KeyError at POST /posts key :topics not found in: %{changeset: #Ecto.Changeset

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm adding more fields to a form:

I added them to post.ex

```
field :name_of_gallery, :string
field :future_plans_title, :string
```

added them to the changeset in stories.ex:

```
     defp post_changeset(%Post{} = post, attrs \\ %{}) do
      post
      |> cast(attrs, [:title, :body, :user_id, :published, :original_post_id, :topic_id, :plan, :done_so_far_one, :done_so_far_two, :done_so_far_three, :done_so_far_one_title, :done_so_far_two_title, :done_so_far_three_title, :name_of_gallery, :future_plans_title])
      |> cast_attachments(attrs, [:project_pic])
      |> validate_required([:title, :body, :user_id, :topic_id, :plan, :done_so_far_one, :done_so_far_two, :done_so_far_three,  :done_so_far_one_title, :done_so_far_two_title, :done_so_far_three_title, :project_pic, :name_of_gallery, :future_plans_title]) 
  end
```

Made two migration files (only one shown here):

```
defmodule Citybuilder.Repo.Migrations.AddNameOfGalleryToFields do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
  alter table (:stories_posts) do
    add :future_plans_title, :string

  end
end
end
```

I ran:

```
mix ecto.drop
mix ecto.setup
mix ecto.migrate
mix run priv/repo/seeds.exs
```

... more than once.

They are in postgres when I check psql:

name_of_gallery         | character varying(255)      | 
 future_plans_title      | character varying(255)

*

The user can't save forms anymore. Saving a user form (which worked before) returns:

```
KeyError at POST /posts
key :topics not found in: %{changeset: #Ecto.Changeset<action: :insert, changes: %{body:
```

and an error on line:

```
  <%= select f, :topic_id, topic_select(@conn.assigns.topics), class: "form-control form-control-topic", placeholder: "Select topic." %>
```

I have a topic select menu, but that has never caused problems before.

*

The entire error message (requested) is here:

```
key :topics not found in: %{changeset: #Ecto.Changeset<action: :insert, changes: %{body: "My Project Summary", done_so_far_one: "Done So Far One Body", done_so_far_one_title: "Done So Far One Title", done_so_far_three: "Random Text to Test Form", done_so_far_three_title: "Random Text to Test Form", done_so_far_two: "Random Text to Test Form", done_so_far_two_title: "Random Text to Test Form", name_of_gallery: "Random Text to Test Form", plan: "My Project Plan", project_pic: %{file_name: "person-woman-park-music (1).jpg", updated_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2017-08-08 13:11:46>}, title: "My Project Title", topic_id: 1, user_id: 2}, errors: [future_plans_title: {"can't be blank", [validation: :required]}], data: #Citybuilder.Stories.Post<>, valid?: false>, layout: {Citybuilder.Web.LayoutView, "app.html"}, user: %Citybuilder.Auths.User{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "auths_users">, admin: false, encrypted_password: "$2b$12$MvDVJo01scAyrrBtnT1dpulbuj9uwDnS2ZezFeUhmzol7mJXRBYa6", id: 2, inserted_at: ~N[2017-08-08 12:20:13.948747], moderator: false, password: nil, password_confirmation: nil, updated_at: ~N[2017-08-08 12:20:13.970885], username: "jarvis"}}
```

Controller code for post and new functions here:

```
def new(conn, _params) do
    default_topic = Stories.get_topic!(@default_topic)
    changeset = Stories.change_post(
      %Citybuilder.Stories.Post{},
      %{topic_id: default_topic.id}
    )
    render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
  end

  def create(conn, %{"post" => post_params}) do
    case Stories.create_post(post_params, conn.assigns.user) do
      {:ok, post} ->
        conn
        # |> put_flash(:info, "Post created! ヽ(´▽`)/")
        |> redirect(to: post_path(conn, :show, post))
      {:error, %Ecto.Changeset{} = changeset} ->
        render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
    end
  end
```

Comment: I'd like to see more of the error message, and the line it crashes on. It looks like you're trying to access `changeset.topics` which does not exist in the `Ecto.Changeset` struct.

Comment: It crashes on line 78,  last line in the question.  <%= select f, :topic_id, topic_select(@conn.assigns.topics), class: "form-control form-control-topic", placeholder: "Select topic." %>... I'll pastebin the error.

Comment: Can you post your controller code?

Comment: Oh I actually misread the line there. You just haven't included the `:topic` key in your assigns for some reason.

Comment: narrowtux, should I add it in here:  <%= select f, :topic, :topic_id, topic_select... I reverted to an older commit this morning so that may be the problem. Dogbert, I haven't changed the controller code, I'll post it if i can't resolve it in the form.

Comment: @Dogbert, added controller code for post and new functions.

Comment: @RubyRube you aren't assigning `:topics` in a call to `render` so `@conn.assigns` does not have `:topics` key. That's either in the controller (if that template code is in `new.html`) or from where ever you're calling `render` for that template.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed this line:

```
 plug :set_topics when action in [:index, :new, :edit, :update, :fork]
```

to this:

```
plug :set_topics when action in [:index, :new, :edit, :create, :update, :fork]
```

added create function. Form passes the compiler now, but there are still some validation errors.

*

To fix form validations:

I had some fields in my changeset:

```
  defp post_changeset(%Post{} = post, attrs \\ %{}) do
 post
    |> cast(attrs, [:title, :body, :user_id, :published, :original_post_id, :topic_id, :plan, :done_so_far_one, :done_so_far_two, :done_so_far_three, :done_so_far_one_title, :done_so_far_two_title, :done_so_far_three_title, :name_of_gallery, :future_plans_title])
    |> cast_attachments(attrs, [:project_pic])
    |> validate_required([:title, :body, :user_id, :topic_id, :plan, :done_so_far_one, :done_so_far_two, :done_so_far_three,  :done_so_far_one_title, :done_so_far_two_title, :done_so_far_three_title, :project_pic, :name_of_gallery, :future_plans_title])
```

that were not present in form.html.eex. When the form is validated Phoenix/Ecto expects all fields. A missing field returns a flash error for an unvalidated form.